# Parsing numbers with bitwise operators and alternatives

Tags: javascript

I've seen different solutions of converting strings to numbers and would like some convention to go by.

I had this trick stored up:

```
"55" >> 0
```

Which works fine for this small number but lets take this oddly specific number:

```
"1450088100000" >> 0
```

and this produces a negative result while

```
Number("1450088100000")
```

works fine.

1. Should one always use `Number()` and just ignore these bitwise tricks?
2. Are there any arguably valuable use cases for the first example compared to the third one?

```js
console.log("55" >> 0)
console.log("1450088100000" >> 0)
console.log(Number("1450088100000"))
```

Comment: That lack of readability alone is a good enough reason not to resort to tricks like `>> 0`. What's wrong with `parseInt`? (although I am personally partial to using unary`+`)

Comment: *Are there any arguably valuable use cases for the first example compared to the third one?* - you want to look clever?

Comment: @MattBurland I myself use the unary plus ( `+` ) to convert to number, because I know that it uses the same algorithm as `Number()` internally. Not many people knows this. Hence I sometimes add a comment "cast to number". (comments get minified out eh ...)

Comment: @MattBurland Not at all. I want to hear if there are any valuable use cases for the method. I can find valuable use cases for Number such as *it works* in this case. But I struggle to find any defendable arguments for using the bitwise method.

Comment: @E.Sundin: And you have your answer. It's less readable and often doesn't work the way you might expect it to. Using bitwise operators for anything other than what they were intended for is probably a *really bad idea*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript numbers are always floating-point numbers (there's only one number type in JavaScript, unlike most languages), but there are a few ways to force a value into a number, that work differently:

- `Number(x)`, `parseFloat(x)` and `+x` will all give `x` as a floating-point number.
- `parseInt(x)` will give `x` as an integer.
- `x | 0` and `x >> 0` will give `x` as a *signed*  32-bit integer. (In general, this applies to most bitwise operators.)
- `x >>> 0` will give `x` as an *unsigned* 32-bit integer.

I would recommend that you use `Number`, `parseFloat` or `parseInt` depending on your requirements, as these are most clear and intuitive.

Comment: *parseInt(x)...will all give x as a signed 32-bit integer* - try `parseInt("1450088100000")` and you'll see that's obviously not true

Comment: " _Note that parseFloat and parseInt give an exception when the input cannot be interpreted as a number_ " IIRC it returns NaN. It doesn't give an exception.

Comment: @MattBurland You are indeed correct, I corrected my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should *always* ignore the bitewise tricks. Arguably the correct way to transform a string to int in Javascript is [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt). The number function is also a decent option, though it can convert *any sort of object* to a number.

The other two I gather are artefacts of the weak typing in JS. Even if they worked as expected I would not use them, because they're unintuitive for most programmers, and generally seem like a hack.

Comment: " _The number function is also a decent option, though it can convert anything to a number._ " Try `parseInt('012eara')` against `Number('012eara')` 

Comment: @KarelG this was more in the vein of  - it can interpret any sort of object as a number, not necessarily that it accepts the most strings. I'd say parseInt('012eara') is actually a bad behaviour - it should return NaN, rather than trying to force it into number.

Comment: Either add clarification or correct the sentence that I've quoted. `Number()` is more strict on that than `parseInt()` which is more flexible. The former even fails to detect if the argument is an octal while the latter can parse it. ( `Number('010') = 10, parseInt('010') = 8 , parseInt('010', 10) = 10` )